# Focus cursor after inserting text in textfield

Tags: javascript

I made the following function to insert a message (msg) into a textfield.

After inserting the text the cursor needs to be after the last character of the msg that was inputted. The textfield already contains some text.

When I insert the message the cursor gets focussed somewhere near the end of the msg but certainly not after the last character. It seems like some characters don't get counted by .length?

```
     function insertAtCursor(msg) {
           var textArea = document.getElementsByName("message")[0];
           textArea.value = textArea.value.substr(0, textArea.selectionStart) + msg +        textArea.value.substr(textArea.selectionEnd);
           var endMsgPos = textArea.value.lastIndexOf(msg) + msg.length;
           textArea.setSelectionRange(endMsgPos, endMsgPos);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `textArea.value.lastIndexOf(msg)`.

```
function insertAtCursor(msg) {
    var textArea = document.getElementsByName("message")[0];
    var selStart = textArea.selectionStart, val = textArea.value;
    textArea.value = val.slice(0, selStart) + msg +
                     val.slice(textArea.selectionEnd);
    var endMsgPos = selStart + msg.length;
    textArea.setSelectionRange(endMsgPos, endMsgPos);
}
```

Comment: thanks! This is definitely working. However when I enter longer texts the cursor doesn't stay after the msg text but skips ahead a couple of characters into the text underneath it. Could this be because the msg text contains /n or special characters? (URL's)

Comment: @Bunker: Which browser?

Comment: Chrome, it's for a Chrome extension :-)

Comment: @Bunker: Should be fine then. Got some example text that fails?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I just found the problem was indeed because  of the difference \n is counted in length and selectionstart. Once I added the following it worked like a charm: var endMsgPos = selStart + msg.length - msg.match(/\n/g).length ;

Comment: @Bunker, Excuse me for raising this, but it would be nice if you would provide all the info from the start.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll have an issue with IE 8 if you try to use `textArea.selectionStart` because it uses a different API.

Secondly `lastIndexOf` will behave strange in your code if the caret is at the begging of the string and somewhere at the end the value of the msg is present.

Try this:

```
   function insertAtCursor(msg) {
     var e = document.getElementsByName('message')[0],
     length = msg.length, val = e.value;
     /* mozilla / dom 3.0 */
     if ('selectionStart' in e){
       var partial = val.slice(0, e.selectionStart) + msg;
       e.value = partial + val.slice(e.selectionEnd);
       var end = partial.length; 
       e.setSelectionRange(end, end);
     }
     /* exploder */
     if (document.selection){
         e.focus();
         document.selection.createRange().text = msg;
     }
   }
```

The demo is here : http://jsbin.com/UnOBUbU/6